# monacaでNFCを使用したAndroidアプリ開発は可能でしょうか

Tags: android, monaca

まだmonacaでの開発もしたことがないのですが、monacaでNFCを使用したAndroidアプリ開発をしたいと思っています。
標準プランのCordovaプラグインの一覧にはバーコードスキャナのプラグインはありますが、NFCについては見当たりません。

Goldプランではプラグインをインポートすることもできるようですが、標準プランではできないようです。

有料プランへの変更は構わないのですが、実際にmonacaで使用可能なNFCプラグインがなければ意味が無いので、

- monacaで使用可能なNFCプラグインがあるか
- Goldプランで組み込みは可能か
- サンプルプログラム等、組み込みの指南

をお聞きできればと思います。

お手数ですが教えていただけないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「回答」というレベルにはできないのでコメント欄にて。Goldプランで独自に開発したCordovaプラグインは利用可能になりますが、Cordova 4.1で動作するプラグインでないといけないのでその点注意が必要です

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！一番欲しいところの回答をいただけたので、とてもうれしいです。
Goldプランにアップグレードしてみたいと思います。
本当にありがとうございます。